# Where to define SSL config for multiple nginx server blocks

Tags: nginx

I want to redirect http to https, and naked to www.

So my config:

```
# http naked -> https www
# http www -> https www
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  return 301 https://www.example.com$request-uri;
}


# https naked -> https www
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name example.com;
  #ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem     # <--- ??
  #ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem   # <--- ??
  return 301 https://www.$host$request-uri;
}


# https www
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name www.example.com;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
}
```

Do I need to repeat the SSL stuff shown as `??` in the middle block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every ssl virtualhost must define key/cert. So in your case if you wrote "listen ... ssl", you have to write ssl_certificate lines. It is not important, if that key/cert pair will be used for anything else.

You can have aliases. I.e. if your key/cert pair in /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com is valid for both example.com and www.example.com (i.e. that is SAN certificate), and you want to serve same content from www.example.com and example.com without redirect, you can have only one ssl vhost in nginx: server_name example.com www.example.com;

You can do redirect even in this case, but I think it is easier to understand and maintain a config if those are distinct vhosts.

Comment: Thanks! So every ssl server block must have certs, *even if all it does is redirect?*

Comment: Yes, it does a redirect ony /after/ initialising a TLS session. Absolutely any HTTP activity in HTTPS is only possible after TLS session setup. Session setup is initiated by Client Hello message, to which TLS server answers with its certificate. Then, after some cryptographic math, they both securely create a secret shared session key. That math requires server to also have a key corresponding to its certificate. This is actually the way to achieve a provably secure communication. If redirect was made possible without TLS, then MitM would be able hijack your visitors to MitM-crafted site.

Comment: Thanks! Also, I don't understand your second point - I thought I need three blocks: one from naked to www, one for http to https and a last "real" one... Are you saying I only need two?

Comment: You may create a single Nginx virtual host that supports multiple hostnames. For HTTPS case, all these hostnames have to be valid in its certificate, and such certificate would be called a SAN cert (ordinary cert has a name in required common name = "CN" field, and alternative domain names are specified in optional subjectAltName = "SAN" field). "www.example.com" and "example.com" are distinct names, and you can either have different certs, one for each name, or have a single SAN cert that is valid for both. In the latter case you may set up a single ssl virtual host if you wish.